# Applying bird spike strips to deter squirrels?

Tags: roof, pest-control

I have some squirrel that love running on top of my roof that I'm trying to
get rid of.

I am considering using bird spike strips to deter squirrels from getting on my roof.  I was wondering if applying them on the bottom and sides of the gutters would work.  Has anyone tried doing this?

Context:
I used to have a tree that the squirrel used to get easy access to the roof and it must have hoarded stuff on the roof.  The squirrel is pretty determined since there is no tree branch within 20 feet and the roof is a 2nd story roof.

Comment: Why are the squirrels running on your house? Are there nuts up there? Are there overhanging branches close to the house?

Comment: A better description of the problem and/or photos are needed here. The question is unanswerable as it is.

Comment: First you need to know where/how the are getting on the roof.  Try a plastic bird of prey at the point they are accessing the roof,  one that feeds on squirrels in your area. It works for pigeons.  ??

Comment: The squirrels here are used to that.  They ignore fake owls and rubber snakes.

Comment: You asked if placing the spikes on the bottom and sides of the gutters would help? How would we know you haven't told us how they are getting up there. Are they climbing the siding? A down spout? More info is needed.

Comment: This is the part I don't know.  Since having the tree removed I have no idea how the squirrel is getting up there.  My best guess is the front of the house is covered in brick and the squirrel is scaling that.  The gutters form a perimeter around that side.

Comment: you cannot prevent the squirrel from getting on the roof until you know how the squirrel gets to the roof ...... your question is pointless, you might as  well delete it

Comment: bird spikes do not deter squirels on fences (see amazon reviews) let alone  on a roof where their claws can grip bricks ect to get around. At any rate squirels are far more intelligent than some of these obnoxious commenters asking you to delete!